# VLOOKUP returning #N/A when using 'False' in the formula, not adding 'False' returning random values

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to retrieve values from another sheet, Which has Names,job code, Department  columns in B,C, D respectively. I want to retrieve the Department. If I dont use the 'False' in the formula its returning random Department names. Names are not repeated in the UserDeptReport sheet.

=VLOOKUP("Stephanie Bayun",UserDeptReport!$B2:$D256745,1,FALSE)

Comment: That `1` should be `3` for the *third* column of the lookup table.

Comment: When omitting False or using True the match is relative, which means the lookup range should be sorted ascending.  False returns an exact match search and if the spelling is not exact it will return an error.

Comment: updated 1 to 3, and sorted asceding order for the look value. Still returning error, If 'False' omitted then random values are returned. Please help to get exact match with the Name.=VLOOKUP("Stephanie Bayun",UserDeptReport!$B2:$D256745,3,FALSE),

Comment: Then there is a spelling error in the data.  a match is not being found.

Comment: no spelling error, copy/pasted name from the retrieving sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging your formula by doing the following:

1. Copy the name `Stephanie Bayun` from your `UserDeptReport` sheet and paste it in Cell `A1` of a new worksheet;
2. In cell `B1` of the new worksheet, enter the following formula and see if it returns the desired outcome:

   `=VLOOKUP(A1,UserDeptReport!$B2:$D256745,1,0)`
3. If yes, manually type the name `Stephanie Bayun` in cell `C1` and test if it is the same as the name in cell `A1` using `=C1=A1`. If the result is `FALSE`, use `=LEN(A1)` and `LEN(C1)` to find out if there they are the same length. If one is longer than the other, the longer one (which could well be the one in cell `A1`) must have some spaces in front of at the end of the string. One way to fix that is to use **TRIM** function to clean up the names on your `UserDeptReport` sheet;
4. If you still cannot figure out where went wrong, maybe share your worksheet via google drive, one drive or similar online host so I can have a look for you.

Comment: Thank you for the all the inputs. Its resolved, by moving the lookup column in UserDeptReport to be the first column A. It was in in column C.